# Async Timer on Rxjs

Tags: angular, angular2-services, rxjs5

The main goal of my task is create timer that will be launching every n second. The project is writing on angular 2 so the best way is using Observable.

So what I'm trying to do:

```
export interface IAsyncTimer {
    timerObservable: Observable<any>
    observables: Array<Observable<any>>
}

@Injectable()
export class AsyncTimer {
    private timers: Map<number, IAsyncTimer> = new Map<number, IAsyncTimer>();

    public addTimer(time: number,
                    func: Observable<any>) {
        let timer = this.timers.get(time);

        if (!!timer) {
            timer.observables.push(func);
        }
        else {
            let observable = Observable.interval(time)
                                       .timeInterval(),
                timer      = {
                    timerObservable: observable,
                    observables    : [func]
                };
            timer.timerObservable.switchMap(Observable.forkJoin.apply(Observable, timer.observables)).subscribe(() => {});
            this.timers.set(time, timer);
        }
    }
}
```

For example I have few component on page. Each component get data itself. Component should be updated every 10 seconds. So I'm injecting AsyncTimer and add request in timer.

Comment: It is not clear why class instance hosts multiple timers. What's the reason to use it as a container for timers? The question says only about a single timer.

Comment: @estus if I have few request that should be sending every n seconds I need one timer

Comment: But why is there a map of multiple timers and why should `func` observable be supplied? Usually an exemplary implementation is welcome in questions, but here it creates the wrong impression about what you're trying to do. The code and the requirements in the question are different.

Comment: @estus I need to create timer that will be waiting while request are finishing and relaunch them after n seconds.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't clear enough what this should mean. What will happen if the requests finish at different time, should they become asynchronous? What will happen if one of the requests won't finish within 10 seconds? Basically it is as simple as having a `(time) => Rx.Observable.interval(time)` factory provider and using `concat` on it.

Comment: @estus In other words the easiest way is to create timer for each request?

Comment: Most likely, yes. You can share 10 seconds interval observable as a service if you need a common one, but that's pretty much all. `AsyncTimer` looks like an overkill and is prone to memory leaks.